# So it looks like [tag:e3d-hermes] should be changed to [tag:e3d-hemera]

Tags: support, tags

Without going into the specifics (because I don't know them) E3D got into a bit of hot water with the name of their new Hermes extruder and determined that just renaming the extruder to Hemera would make life easier. Is there a way to change [e3d-hermes](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-hermes) to [e3d-hemera](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e3d-hemera) and perhaps make the former synonymous with the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to rename tags, but it would indeed be better to create a synonym as the extruder has had the Hermes name for a while. This means the Hermes tag will be replaced by the Hemera tag after adding/confirming the tag in the question.

---

**Update:**

Has been done, there where only 2 questions.